# How to check value of inputfile in apex repeat on save with javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, repeat, onchange, function

I have a visualforce page where I give the option to save 2 files based on an apex repeat.
I check when a file is added on change if the filesize does not surpass 5mb and alert the user if needed. On saving I want to be sure that both inputfiles are filled. If not I want to alert the user to add 2 files. How can I check for both of the inputfiles if they are filled? I suppose I need to call a function onchange of the save button but how do I get the id's of the 2 inputFiles? Do I need to make the id="inputfile" dynamic?

Visualforce

```
      <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">
                                        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"  />
                                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!rowNum == 1}" >
                                            <apex:outputLabel value="CV *" rendered="{!rowNum == 1}" ></apex:outputLabel>
                                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!rowNum == 2}" >
                                            <apex:outputLabel value="Motivation *" rendered="{!rowNum == 2}" ></apex:outputLabel>
                                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                            <apex:outputLabel value=""></apex:outputLabel>
                                            <apex:inputFile id="inputfile"

                                                            value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"
                                                            onchange="checkFileSize(event,id)"/>
                                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                    </apex:repeat>

..

          <apex:commandLink id="inputfile"
                              styleClass="button" style="text-decoration:none;"
                              value="SUBMIT APPLICATION"
                              action="{!saveLead}"
                              onclick="checkFileCount(event,id)" />
            <apex:actionFunction name="saveLead" action="{!saveLead}"/>

    <script>
    function checkFileSize(event,id) {
        if(event.target.files[0].size > 2**20*5) {
            alert('File must be less than 5Mb');
            document.getElementById(id).value =''; 
        } 

        else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who bumps into this. Asof this writing it is currently not possible to bind dynamic id. We can only get the Id by the trigger of the event.

Answer (score -1):

To identify the element from JS you have to navigate through your structure, from the root component. It will be easier for you if you put id's in all your parent component. It would be something like:

`document.getElementById('{!$Component.ApexBlockSectionItemID.inputfile}');`

In regards to iterating through the items that your for-loop is creating, maybe you can tackle those items by creating dynamic custom ids and making a for-loop of the size of your variable {!newAttachments} in your javascript that iterates over them.

For example, you can create an `id="inputfile+{!rowNum}"`

And then write JS like:

```
function checkIfEmpty(theSizeOfnewAttachments){
 for(let i=0; i>theSizeOfnewAttachments ;i++){
  let element = document.getElementById(...inputfile+i) //your path to the item
  if (element==null){
   //your error message;
  return
   }
 } 
}
```

Here you have a similar question that can put you in the right direction:
[get inputFieldValue into variable in JS](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I5BSQA0)

Hope this helps :)
P/S: this is only pseudo-code!

Comment: id="inputfile+{!rowNum}". throws an error:Literal value is required for attribute id in <apex:inputFile>

Comment: It is currently not possible to bind dynamic id

Comment: If you already found the answer to your question, I suggest you post an answer and select it as the correct one in order to keep this tidy. Sorry my answer didn't help you find your way through your problem.